# What does the TARDIS pump?

Tags: doctor-who

The interior design of TARDIS changes over time, but one thing remains common among all designs: A transparent vertical tube in the center (around which controls exist).

The interior of tube also changes whenever TARDIS renews it's design, but it always feels like something is pumped whenever TARDIS flies across Time and Space (internal mechanism stand still when TARDIS sits somewhere doing nothing).

What is pumped inside that tube (I don't know it's name if it has one)? Is it Time Vortex (I concluded this because the tube comes out of heart of TARDIS which contains Time Vortex)?

Only canonical answers, please.

Comment: Could very well be, that nothing is pumped, that it's just moving up and down. The sound that (at least to me) triggered the pump-association is made by the handbrake. Without the handbrake there is no pumping-sound.

Comment: @Einer - we don't know if the sound has anything to do with a "handbrake", I suspect that was just a joke on River Song's part, since every other TARDIS used by other Time Lords like The Master and the Rani has made the same sound.

Comment: @SachinShekhar Theres no such thing as Doctor Who canon. It's whatever you or the writer wants it to be.

Comment: @calccrypto Well then, I meant non-fan official publications like TV series, comics etc.

Comment: @Hypnosifl One part of me agrees with calccrypro. The other part says: "But she could fly that thing without the noise!" Maybe the handbrake-part is a pun, but she has demonstrated that the noise is unnecessary - that the Tardis can move without triggering pumping-associations.

Comment: @Hypnosifl River Song probably did something right nonetheless. As to why other TARDIS' make the noise: it was probably because the show designers at the time were more concerned with other things than changing an iconic part of Doctor Who (if the Doctor's TARDIS does it, why don't all TARDIS' do it?), and left/put the sound in.

Comment: @Einer As I recalled, the handbrake part was attached with landing (reaching destination). While flying, River just stabilized the TARDIS by hitting the blue button.

Comment: @calccrypto River learned that trick from future Doctor, so maybe past Doctors and others don't know about it.

Comment: @SachinShekhar Future Doctor? That was mentioned somewhere? I'll admit I don't read the books or comics, but I don't remember hearing about a Future Doctor from River Song in the TV episodes. I do, however, remember her saying something about learning how to fly the TARDIS while the Doctor decided to skip the class.

Comment: @calccrypto What do you think about that Time Lord class... Man, she was joking. River and The Doctor always meet across Time in wrong order. She was very close to future Doctor in her past, so you can logically conclude from where she could learn that.

Comment: @calccrypto There are always clear mention of future Doctor. She has photos of all past Doctors (that's how she recognizes one). Future Doctor gave her a Sonic Screwdriver which helped past Doctor to save her (into library computer) after she died. She has a notebook of her past which can reveal Doctor's future (which he dropped on the library planet).

Comment: @SachinShekhar oh. for some reason, I misinterpreted future doctor as in "future regenerations", not "same doctor, reverse timeline". sorry

Comment: @calccrypto No, she has history with future regenerations.

Comment: @SachinShekhar did i miss something major? I remember the journal, but still...

Comment: @calccrypto When she died, she was with 10th Doctor. When she silenced TARDIS, she was with 11th Doctor. Both Doctors knew nothing about her, but she knew everything about him. Watch all River Song episodes again..

Comment: Aether. Also, chocolate sauce.

Comment: @SachinShekhar yeah. on screen, we see her with the 10th and 11th Doctors. The way I misunderstood your previous comments was: she interacted with Doctors 12, 13... which we wouldn't know about yet, unless you are a time traveler

Comment: The answer is deceptively simple - it's a coffee machine. The doctor like a good cuppa.
Here's the Time Rotor for the next redesign of the Tardis. http://de-bang.org/?post_type=portfolio&p=1673&ckattempt=1

Answer (score 10):

The "pump" as you call it is called the [time rotor](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Time_rotor). This was mentioned by at least the First Doctor and probably a few times in the new series as well. I don't remember specific lines/episodes well enough to say where and when.

The TARDIS Data Core's description makes it seem like a glorified status indicator that signifies the TARDIS' engines are operating properly:

> The time rotor was a component in the central column of the TARDIS
>   console. While the TARDIS was in flight, the rotor rose and fell,
>   stopping when the TARDIS reached a destination. It was associated with
>   the 'whooshing' noise heard when the TARDIS was in flight. The time
>   rotor was connected to the lower engines; hence as the TARDIS moved
>   the rotor moved accordingly. As well as signifying the TARDIS'
>   movement, the rotor was also known to stop working when something went
>   wrong, e.g. the rotor stopped moving as the TARDIS engines stalled.
>   This might be rectified by thumping the console.

As to what the rotor *actually* does, the answer is probably whatever a writer decides it does, or [it just goes up and down because thats what it does](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fq-nqBIERhg).

[image: Old Time Rotor]
[image: 11's Time Rotor]

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question of "what is pumped". However, there's no real reason to think the up-and-down movement of the time rotor is because it's "pumping" some substance, and there's no mention of such a thing in the fairly extensive "time rotor" article on the Doctor Who wiki: http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Time_rotor ...also as noted in the article, the Rani's TARDIS had a different type of time rotor involving a set of rotating rings (similar to the ones on Krypton in the original Superman movie) that weren't in a tube, so apparently a Time Rotor doesn't need to rise and fall.

Comment: @Hypnosifl fair enough. I added a bit. From the wiki, it seems like the rotor doesn't really do much

Comment: nice job, although I would quibble with the idea that there's any reason to think its movement was a mere "status indicator", as opposed to something more functional. Maybe you got that from the use of "signifying" but I think that was just a word choice of some random wiki editor that you shouldn't read too much into, they may have just meant that the show's designers use it as a signifier of travel to the audience, not that its specific purpose is to "signify" anything to the characters in an in-universe sense.

Comment: @Hypnosifl I see what you mean. The actual answer is probably "whatever the writer wants the rotor to do"

Comment: We can in fact be pretty *sure* that it does *something* useful, as the TARDIS has been grounded more than once when there was a problem specifically with the Time Rotor.

Comment: Shouldn't a rotor... *rotate*? But hey, if you can reverse to polarity of particles that don't have polarity, why not a rotor that goes up and down?

Answer (score 1):

Like others have said it is the Time Rotor, and when charged and liberated, it will begin to go up and down, making that whoosing sound, pumping Artron Energy into the Dynamorphic Generators and the Dematerialisation Circuit, allowing the displacement of the TARDIS (via normal space or via Time Vortex).
Also, there are Time Rotors that don't go up and down, like the one in the Junkyard TARDIS from the Doctor's Wife.

EDIT: Its not like it "pumps", it allows the energy to be pumped:"the Rotor provides access to the richest source of temporal energy on a TARDIS. The Rotor holds the power of the Heart of the TARDIS in check by "weighing it down" to prevent its escape" "Each space-time jump drains the Time Rotor's Energy Storage Unit""It takes a TARDIS 12 minutes to charge the Energy Storage Unit with Temporal Energy for another space-time jump. This is done using the Temporal Reactors fuelled by Artron Energy."

Comment: Haha.. Nice one. Any citation for that? Or, you just made everything up by yourself?

Comment: http://www.whoniverse.net/tardis/dynomorphicpower

Comment: http://www.whoniverse.net/tardis/timecolumn Also, in the 7 season when one of the Van Vaalen bros pointed the console with the Intelligent sensor, getting the result of Conceptual Geometers and Dynamorphic generators, so they are at least located in the control room.

Comment: Nice one. But, how legit are the sources?

Comment: That page contains the contens of the series, the comics, the audio books and the movies, is one of the biggest and more extended that i have found, that merge all the contents marking then by source. I just dont see the point in make such a big marked archive that is all fake. Also it is marked when it is speculated theories or unofficial.

Comment: Still, I didn't find anything about Time Rotor pumping there. Can you please quote relevant sentences from that page?

Comment: Its not like it "pumps", it allows the energy to be pumped:"the Rotor provides access to the richest source of temporal energy on a TARDIS. The Rotor holds the power of the Heart of the TARDIS in check by "weighing it down" to prevent its escape" "Each space-time jump drains the Time Rotor's Energy Storage Unit""It takes a TARDIS 12 minutes to charge the Energy Storage Unit with Temporal Energy for another space-time jump. This is done using the Temporal Reactors fuelled by Artron Energy."

Comment: Then, better re-write your answer. Also, don't forget to add quotes and citations.

Comment: Ok, sorry I am a newbie in this!

Answer (score -4):

actually the Time Rotor stores power for the demat circuit and when it is moving that means it is dematerializing or in flight but it uses the stored power for the demat

Comment: A reference would be amazing. First time I hear about this.

Comment: If you can provide some proof for this claim, it's likely your downvotes will become upvotes.